# elif condition not working properly for string matching in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, matching

I am developing a webscraping code, while doing so i am trying to modify the code as to extract specific element if the website link has a string from the predefined list of strings. I am trying to do this with the help of if elif condition.

the context is something similar to this:

```
list1 = ["apple","bat"]
list2 = ["cat", "mat"]

tester = ["www.cat.com","www.website.com","www.apple.com"]
for a in tester:
    print(a)
    if (item1 in a for item1 in list1):
        print("apple is present")
    elif ("john" in a):
        print("failed")
    elif (item2 in a for item2 in list2):
        print("cat is present")
```

but the problem is the match is not happening properly, the loop is giving the output of the first condition , not going to the second check condition. any suggestion as on how to overcome this behavior ?

Output i got is:

```
apple is present
apple is present
apple is present
```

Comment: The expression `(item1 in a for item1 in list1)` is a generator, and the truth value of a generator is `True` hence if generator is always `True`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, now i understood the reason behind the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the if is always succeeding rather than the elif, then the problem is that if itself, not the elif.

In your case you are missing the `any`:

```
if any(item1 in a for item1 in list1):
```

Comment: very simple yet vital part "**Any**" solved my problem for both general and in selenium webdriver. Thank you very much @Daniel Roseman